# Using a custom UITableView in UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

So I had a VC that was 700+ lines of code so I decided to refactor and throw all the table view logic into it's own class. I thought this would be very similar to making a custom UITableViewCell. I made the custom class and copy pasted all the functionality I had in the VC. In the storyboard I changed the class from UITableView to my custom class. Removed my VC  as the delegate and datasource.

However, when I run it, the app loads but the tableView is empty.

Any ideas I missing something vital here?

Comment: Need to see some code

Comment: Like what? Not gonna just post 400 lines of code :)

Comment: Well have you logged any of the table view delegate methods to see if they are being called?

Comment: No they are not being called

Comment: @Boid, I started to work on a library that should make populating tableviews and collection views much easier by using a populator that takes a datasource object. I am using it in serveral projects and found it flawless so far, as it does not require to deal with custom subclasses, does not limit to implement everything  programmatically vs storyboarding. here it's site http://vikingosegundo.github.io/ofapopulator/ , but I am still writing that text. https://github.com/vikingosegundo/ofaexample contains a simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are stupid. Views should not manage content. Instead they should present content set from the outside in a *reusable* way. A view with static content isn't really usable.

If you want to subclass `UITableView` to manage colors, insets, go for it. But its content should not be managed by itself, but instead by a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the tableView's dataSource and delegate to your new subclass? Essentially, to `self`?

Comment: Where exactly would I do this? There is no viewDidLoad() in UITableView. Do I have to make an IBOutlet of table in the VC and than make an instance of my UITableView class and set it to that?

Comment: One of the initialization methods would be an appropriate place.